# Compilation error saying cordova not available?

Tags: android, reactjs, cordova, camera, phonegap

I am building this app with Phonegap and React. When I include cordova.js inside the HTML template footer of my React project and use the Camera plugin inside of a React component and run build so that I can copy the build project to Phonegap's www folder, webpack comes up with an error that Camera is not available. Of course Camera plugin of Cordova will be available later at runtime when phonegap server will run once I copy the build folder to Phonegap's www folder and run the Phonegap server.

My question is how to include Cordova and it's camera plugin to React so that webpack finds it but doesn't add the dependency to compiled JavaScript file as the cordova library with all it's plugins will be also available later when Phonegap is run with the built files of React/webpack.

Here are my code and folder structures-

HTML-

```
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/plugins.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>

</body>
```

React component-

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import * as allActions from '../../actions/basket';
    import restaurant_image from '../../assets/images/pictures/2t.jpg';

    class Basket extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.deviceReady = this.deviceReady.bind(this);
          this.state = {
            restaurants_info: [],
            showInput: false,
            posts_awaiting: 0,
            button_disabled: true
          }
      }


      deviceReady () {
        window.cordova.plugins.Camera.getPicture(this.onSuccess, this.onFail, { quality: 70, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, allowEdit: true });
      }

      onSuccess(imageURI) {
        var image = document.getElementById('urlImage');
        image.src = imageURI;

        image.style.display = 'block';

        console.log(imageURI);
      }

      onFail(message) {
        console.log(message);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceReady);
      }
      render() {

      const imgStyle = {
        maxWidth: "100%"
      }

        return (
                <button onClick={this.deviceReady} className="button button-round button-xs uppercase ultrabold button-xs button-center button-orange">TakePic</button>
                <img alt="bello" id="urlImage"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
      }

    }

    function mapStateToProps(state, prop) {
      return {
        posts_added: state.posts_added,
        posts_basketed: state.posts_basketed,
        awaiting_added: state.awaiting_added
      }
    }

    function mapDispatchToProp(dispatch) {
      return {
        action: bindActionCreators(allActions, dispatch)
      }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProp)(Basket);
```

And here is the app structure-
I am running build command on React and copying over the build files to Phonegap's www folder-

[image]